# How to SELECT most common (viral) from a table and LIMIT results for pagination?

Tags: mysql, join, select, order-by, count

> Sorry if it's a dubplicate but I can't find an answer to the question.

Hello there so I have three tables users and articles and likes, a user can write an article, in the table articles there is also a timestamp column and can be liked by other users where a like is saved in likes table with the user id and secret id.
 
articles table:

```
+----+---------+--------------------+
| id | article |       timestamp    |
+----+---------+--------------------+
| 1  | A       |2019-02-10 22:19:02 |
| 2  | B       |2019-02-9 22:20:28  |
| 3  | C       |2019-02-9 22:21:10  |
| 4  | D       |2019-02-8 18:20:10  |   
| 5  | E       |2019-02-8 13:25:04  |
+----+---------+--------------------+
```

likes table:

```
+-----------+--------+
| articleid | userid |
+-----------+--------+
| 1         | 1      |
| 1         | 3      |
| 1         | 5      |
| 1         | 3      |
| 2         | 1      |
| 3         | 2      |
| 3         | 3      |
| 3         | 4      |
| 3         | 5      |
| 3         | 2      |
| 4         | 4      |
+-----------+--------+
```

I'm trying to do the pagination of the most liked articles in the shortest time,
 as for example in this case article A is the top of the order because it got more likes in less time, 
 
 How would I do that and at the same time LIMIT the result to do the pagination?
My try was:

```
SELECT * FROM articles, (SELECT count(*) FROM likes WHERE articleid = id) as likes
GROUP BY articles
OREDER BY likes
LIMIT 10
```

I would do it in php without LIMIT but at the same time I want to repeat the query to get the next articles for the second page in the same way and I have no idea how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ref: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Comment: @danblack I'm not only trying to do the pagination but also choose most liked articles in the shortest time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the database is more than a 'toy', you will need to keep an up-to-date (or nearly so) table of actual like-counts.  It would have *two* columns: article_id and like_ct with `article_id` as the PK.

With that (plus a `JOIN`) you can do an efficient pagination *without* `OFFSET`.

> most liked in the last day or two days

Start with a 2-column table:

```
CREATE TABLE Likes (
    article_id ...,   -- for JOINing to Articles
    ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (article_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This should give you the list of article_ids ordered by most likes in the last 2 days, counting back from the instant the query was run.

```
SELECT article_id,
       COUNT(*) AS like_ct
    FROM Likes
    WHERE ts >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
    GROUP BY article_id
    ORDER BY tot_likes DESC
```

With `LIMIT 10` you can get the top 10.  With `OFFSET` you can *inefficiently* get other 'pages'.

Use the above as a "derived" table and `JOIN Articles USING(article_id)` to get other info.

Comment: And how do I do that relatively to time, as in ordering by most liked in shortest time?

Comment: @CasperX - Be more precise in that ordering definition.  "Max number in the last hour" will give you one list; "max number in the last week" is likely to give you quite a different list.  Offhand, I can't think of a formula that gives a realistic metric somewhere between those.

Comment: tbh idk how to be precise with words, well let's say article 1 had 4 likes in 1hr and article 2 had 5 likes in 2hrs, in the way I want to order the articles I would like article 1 to show first and article 2 to show after, even so it has more likes, but relatively to time article 1 is more viral. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @CasperX - You are saying (4 likes / 1 hour = 4.0) > ( 5 likes / 2 hr = 2.5) and if article 3 has 1 like in 5 minutes ( 1 / (1/12 hour) = 12.0 ), does that go to the top of the list?  And 48 likes in a day (48/24 = 2.0) at the bottom of the list?

Comment: @CasperX - But when does the "nnn Hours" start?  When the article is posted?  Or when the site is opened for business?  Example:  a boring post that has been sitting there for a week, then gets 4 likes in the last hour -- high? or low in the ranking?

Comment: @CasperX - Whatever metric you pick needs to be understandable by your users.  Examples:  (1) "Total likes" (regardless of when posted); (2) "Likes in the last day" (but then need to define "day" -- UTC, through NOW(), etc); (3)...

Comment: Well I'm planning on using more than one metric but I have no idea how to order relatively to time, what I actually wanted to do was most liked in the last day or two days.

Comment: Based on that, I added more to my Answer.

Comment: So there was actually no way to do it with timestamp from the article, starting from SELECT from articles table, that's why I got to a dead end, right?

Comment: So I should add a timestmap to likes and do one SELECT query on likes table, right?

Comment: One last time ORDER BY tot_likes, where di "tot_likes" come from? shouldn't it be count(*)?

Comment: If you want to count only the Likes in the last couple of days, you need a timestamp on the _like_.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY likes DESC` should be used to get the highest likes first.

The second page is going to have `LIMIT 10,10`.

With a `likes` table as it is, its going to be hard to get quick performance out of this. Getting the number of likes into the main articles table would help get a quicker results of this if they are used often. If you need to use both perhaps an `INSERT` trigger on the `likes` table.

Once you have a `likes` column in `articles`, it will need an index on it.

Then your query becomes simply:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
ORDER BY likes DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The second page way is:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
ORDER BY likes DESC
LIMIT 10,10
```

If you got too many pages, you'll eventually start to be slow down as getting 10 pages at an offset needs to walk down to that offset first.

Comment: Adding likes column to articles and keep likes table to keep track of user's likes sounds like a good idea which is a lot easier actually, but I actually wanted to show most liked first relatively to time, how do I do that?